# Monitors not detected by HDMI laptop docking station ports, laptop shuts off when lightly bumped

Tags: laptop, windows-11, hdmi, lenovo-laptop

I've been experiencing an ongoing issue and one that recently came up.

- **Problem #1 (Ongoing)**: my laptop seems to shut down when you give it a bump. It runs fine when you let it sit, but little bumps will shut it off completely and it does a fresh boot next time you turn it on.
- **Problem #2 (Recent)**: I usually work using a laptop docking station. In the docking station, I usually have the power cord, HDMI to a monitor, and a USB keyboard plugged in. Into my laptop, I usually have an HDMI hooked up to a second monitor, and a USB mouse plugged in.

This morning, I tried to turn on my laptop with the setup specified in 2) and the monitor plugged into the HDMI port of the docking station wouldn't work.

#### Things I have tried.

For problem #2: When I plug the monitor that was in the docking station port (DSP), I tried multiple HDMI cables in the DSP, no success. I tried different monitors in the DSP, no success. So he closed and the issue was resolved for a bit, but it has come back.

When I plug the monitor that was in the docking station port (DSP) into the laptop's HDMI port, I get HDMI output to my monitor. I have tried multiple HDMI cables in the DSP, no success. I tried different monitors in the DSP, no success.

Today I bought a new docking station and I was getting HDMI output when plugged into that one's HDMI port for a bit. However, I bumped the laptop and it shut down (problem 1). When I turned it back on, I had lost HDMI output from the new DSP.

I would appreciate any suggestions to solve these issues.

Comment: If it's instantly powering off from a bump, you probably have a loose connection inside the laptop. You can try walking through a laptop teardown on youtube for that model, but a computer repair shop will be better at doing that without breaking anything. The dock hdmi not showing up is odd, but might be related